# C# updating values in two dimensional array

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm converting an Eight Queens solution from Java to C# just to get my head around C# a bit more. The problem is that I'm stuck with changing values on the board. I can change the value inside the function but it goes back to what it was immediately even when I'm using ref. At the moment I'm using a global variable rather than passing the board as an argument.

Here is the code:

```
public static int[,] solution;

    static void Main()
    {
        int n = 8;
        solution = new int[8,8];

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                solution[i,j] = 0;
            }
        }
        Solve(n);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

 public static void Solve(int n)
    {
        if (placeQueens(0, n))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write(" " + solution[i,j]);
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No possible solution");
        }
    }

public static bool placeQueens(int queen, int n)
    {
        if (queen == n)
        {
            return true;
        }
        for (int row = 0; row < n; row++)
        {
            if (canPlace(row, queen))
            {

                solution[row,queen] = 1;

                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                    {
                        Console.Write(" " + solution[i, j]);
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }

                //When I print the current board here the 1 is set
                //When placeQueens is called again it is back to being 0
                if (placeQueens(queen + 1, n))
                {
                    return true;
                }

                solution[row,queen] = 0;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

public static bool canPlace(int row, int col)
{ //Just checks that the position is legal}
```

What can I do to make the 1 stay as a one once I've changed it in placeQueen?

Comment: A class variable is really preferred to passing a parameter, anyway.  Why don't you post the code that DOESN'T work.

Comment: I would add a breakpoint on `solution[row,queen] = 0;` and see if that statement is executing with the right parameters.  As that is the only line setting the values back to zero that might be where the problem lies

Comment: Code looks fine. Passing the array as an argument to the methods should also be fine. Please post the code that is _not_ working rather than the code that works.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the static variable to being passed in each method instead of being a static variable, and it works perfectly:

```
static void Main()
{
    int n = 8;
    var solution = new int[8, 8];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            solution[i, j] = 0;
        }
    }
    Solve(solution, n);
}

public static void Solve(int[,] solution, int n)
{
    if (placeQueens(solution, 0, n))
    {
        Console.WriteLine();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                Console.Write(" " + solution[i, j]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("No possible solution");
    }
}

public static bool placeQueens(int[,] solution, int queen, int n)
{
    if (queen == n)
    {
        return true;
    }
    for (int row = 0; row < n; row++)
    {
        if (canPlace(solution, row, queen))
        {
            solution[row, queen] = 1;

            Console.WriteLine();
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write(" " + solution[i, j]);
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

            if (placeQueens(solution, queen + 1, n))
            {
                return true;
            }

            solution[row, queen] = 0;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public static bool canPlace(int[,] solution, int row, int col)
{
    for (var dx = -1; dx <= 1; dx++)
    {
        for (var dy = -1; dy <= 1; dy++)
        {
            if (dx == 0 && dy == 0)
                continue;

            int r = row, c = col;

            while (r >= 0 && r <= solution.GetUpperBound(0) && c >= 0 && c <= solution.GetUpperBound(1))
            {
                if (solution[r, c] == 1)
                    return false;

                r += dy;
                c += dx;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

The last line it outputs is a correct solution:

```
 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
```